# Extract values from json based on select condition using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to Extract values from json based on select condition using python.
My Json file looks like below:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "user:rohithmn3@gmail.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/browser"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:admin-user@linuxacademy-3.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "user:rohithmn03@gmail.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/owner"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "user:rohithmn3@gmail.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/viewer"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "BwrRsH-UhJ0=",
  "version": 1
}
```

I am trying to parse this above file in python based on the `user`. For Example: Get the roles defined for user `rohithmn3@gmail.com`; as per the json the output should be :

```
roles/browser
roles/viewer
```

Regards,
Rohith

Comment: we're not here to do the job for you, show what you've tried so far

Comment: Hi Azat,
I could able to achieve the same with jq : `cat jsonfile.json | jq -r '.bindings[] | select(.members[]=="user:rohithmn3@gmail.com") | .role' ` ..!
But in python, i couldnot able to parse based on the userid..! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension and dictionary input `d`:

```
var = 'rohithmn3@gmail.com'
res = [subd['role'] for subd in d['bindings'] if 'user:'+var in subd['members']]

print(res)

['roles/browser', 'roles/viewer']
```

**Setup**

```
d = {
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "user:rohithmn3@gmail.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/browser"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:admin-user@linuxacademy-3.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "user:rohithmn03@gmail.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/owner"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "user:rohithmn3@gmail.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/viewer"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "BwrRsH-UhJ0=",
  "version": 1
}
```

Comment: Getting the below error: `TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: @Rohith, I've added my input. Make sure your input is the same, you have refreshed your session and copy-pasted my solution precisely. Otherwise, you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: it's failing because - i could find some \n inside my dict.
I am generating dict in the below way:

`getGCPconsoleCommand = subprocess.Popen(['gcloud', 'projects', 'get-iam-policy', 'linuxacademy-3', '--format', 'json'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`
                              `output = getGCPconsoleCommand.stdout.read().strip()`
                                       `print(output)`

Comment: My dict looks like below :
`'{\n  "bindings": [\n    {\n      "members": [\n        "user:rohithmn3@gmail.com"\n      ],\n      "role": "roles/browser"\n    },\n    {\n      "members": [\n        "serviceAccount:admin-user@linuxacademy-3.iam.gserviceaccount.com",\n        "user:rohithmn03@gmail.com"\n      ],\n      "role": "roles/owner"\n    },\n    {\n      "members": [\n        "user:rohithmn3@gmail.com"\n      ],\n      "role": "roles/viewer"\n    }\n  ],\n  "etag": "BwVvsH-HhI0=",\n  "version": 1\n}\n'`

Comment: @Rohith, Sorry, I can't replicate the problem.